# Convert Values into Table from Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>> in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I Have a Challenge like this,

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>> dic=new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>>();
```

i want them into a table.

Main Problem is, each `Key of dic` is having again a Dictionary with many values.

i want to show them in table.

How can i do this?
please resolve my problem with answer or alternative.

Table will be like this..!
[Desired Output will be Like this.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/UploadFile/kraitz/03242010022629AM/Capture.JPG)

But Please Remove **Top Header,ColA1,ColA2,ColB1,ColB2**...so Table contains **Header1,Col1,Col2**.

*colA1,colB1* were mergend in `Col1` And *ColA2,ColB*2 were merged in `Col2`.

And i am not using LINQ.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want us to suggest a way to present the data? That depends what it actually is. Could you give us an example? Or do you know how you want to view it, you just want help with LINQ etc. to do that?

Comment: try to give a samle what teh result should look like and what kind of table you mean? a flattended Dictionary, HTML table output, CSV, ...?

Comment: edited the description. can you answer plz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one to many relation. So u should have table containing keys from ur dictionary with some primekey, and second table with key, value columns + primekey of corresponding string in first table.

Comment: Thanx for your response. But how can i achieve this...actually i am not using LINQ.is it possible without LINQ Concept.